# How do I apply today's date to images uploaded with ajax and php.

Tags: php, ajax

I have been searching the site for a solution and I found a few, but I do not know how to apply it to the code I am using. I want to add the date & time to the images uploaded by the user.

This is my PHP Page that I am ajaxing the image to.

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("db_connect.php");

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = "uploads/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE users4 SET profile_photo = '".$targetPath."' WHERE username = '".trim($username)."' ";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn)."qqq".$sql);    

            ?>

            <div style="background-position: center;;height:155px;width:240px;background-image: url(<?=$targetPath?>);background-size: 100% auto;background-repeat: no-repeat;border-radius: 8px;" ></div>

            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This my AJAX FUNCTION

```
$.ajax({
    url: "uploadajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(".spinner4").show();
        $(".fa-check").hide();
        $(".upload-preview").hide();
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $("#targetLayer").html(data);
        $("#targetLayer").css('opacity','1');
        setInterval(function() {
            $(".spinner4").hide();
            $(".fa-check").delay(3000).fadeIn(200); 
            $(".button-bottom-container").fadeIn();
        },500);
    },
    error: function() 
    {
    }           
});
```

So I have tried applying.

```
<?php

if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.time().'_'.$name)) {
    echo 'file uploaded! ';
}

?>
```

But with no success. I don't really know where to apply the "time()" function in my code to make it work. Any ideas? I'm sure this is a simple one.

I'm pretty sure the change needs to happen within

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
    $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = "uploads/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
```

but, nothing I try is working. Yet... Thanks if you have some help to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use strtotime()

```
$targetPath = "uploads/".strtotime("now")."_".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
```

To convert back use date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $time);

```
<?
$file_path = "some/directory/1501113258_file.jpg";
$part = explode ("_", basename($file_path));
$date_time = date ("d-m-Y H:i:s", $part['0']);
// will output 26-07-2017 23:54:18
?>
```

Comment: Perfect.. its making my images unique.  the result was 'uploads/1501113123_image.jpg' . I am going to add the time zone and see if it changes to my time. Thanks!

Comment: 5 min timer on the accept. But I will, and thank you for the edit!

Comment: My pleasure :-) Good luck on your project!